# How to copy from URL Parameter to HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Hello i want to ask how to copy url parameter to html text

For example my url is:
`www.domain.com/?id=123456&name=John`

Then i write on html page like this:
HTML:

```
Your ID is <div id="id"></div>
```

Your Name:

Result:

`Your ID is: 123456`

`Your Name is: John`

my question is what the javascript i use to copy url parameter like above to my div html?

Comment: In general, that isn't a good idea in though. That raises XSS vulnerabilities.

Comment: `www.domain.com/id?=123456` is well written?

Comment: i already edit it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get URL parameters from

```
const params = new URL('https://www.example.com/id?=123456').searchParams;
```

Then get the value using

```
params.get('');
```

```js
const params = new URL('https://www.example.com/id?=123456').searchParams;
console.log(params.get(''));

document.getElementById('id').innerHTML = params.get('')


// or else

const params2 = new URL('https://www.example.com?id=123456').searchParams;
console.log(params2.get('id'));
```

```html
Your ID is <div id="id"></div>
```

Comment: How to get current parameter url using ```window.location.href``` ?

Comment: @Almaftuchin let url = new URL(window.location.href).searchParams

Comment: edit:
Thank you very much sir, its working perfectly

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code if you want to get param from `window.location.href`

```js
let url = new URL(window.location.href).searchParams;
const id = url.get('id');
console.log("Your param id :" + id);
```

Answer (score 0):

To parse GET parameters from url you can use something like this :

```
const queryString = window.location.search;

const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);

const id = urlParams.get('id')
console.log(id);
// 123456

const name= urlParams.get('name')
console.log(name);
// John

document.getElementById('id').innerHTML = id;
```